# JS: How would this function get triggered without attaching an event listener on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am looking over Firebase's Cloud Function documentation for triggering emails.  In the code below, `functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)` is a firebase auth event handler for when a user creates an account.  So basically, a welcome email is triggered when a user signs up but how would `functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)` trigger that unless it was an event listener?  I'm just confused at how the 'triggering' is happening -- is that a function expression?

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
// [END onCreateTrigger]

    const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
    const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the 
  user.

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});
```

source: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triggering is controlled by Cloud Functions, and it outside of your control.  It is not really a listener.  It is an event handler.  In this case, Firebase Authentication is the event provider, and it's generating event when accounts are created or deleted.  Cloud Functions receives those events and passes them along to your function.

It's not important to understand how things work behind the scenes.  All you need to know is that your function will get invoked when events occur that match what the function declares that it's looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Doug!.  To be clear, is this a normal way functions are invoked?  I've never seen this type of syntax invoke a function.

Comment: Seems normal for serverless backend programming.